# Force variable to bear only defined values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, types, enums, format

I need to design a log message format that has a property called 'type'. We have already defined exactly four types it can take, these are for simplicity's sake called A,B,C and D.
I wanted to realize it with the help of ENUMS but such a definition does not exist in JavaScript, that's why I wanted to ask how I can define a 'customized' data type with values A,B,C and D so that my type property can only take one of these four values.

Thanks in advance.

```
export class LogMessageFormat {
  type: myType; //here 'type' should only take the above-mentioned values
  time: String;
  source: String;
  target: String;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you want and I don't have the answer for this. But what I've done in such cases is throw an Error if the value is not in the specified range. The difference is compile time vs. runtime reporting

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MessageTypes = {
  A: "A",
  B: "B",
  C: "C",
  D: "D",
};

// If you are concerned with undesired mutation of MessageTypes
// const MessageTypes = Object.freeze({
//   A: "A",
//   B: "B",
//   C: "C",
//   D: "D",
// });


class LogMessageFormat {
  _type = MessageTypes.A
  // .... other props

  get type() {
    return this._type;
  }

  set type(newValue) {

    if (MessageTypes[newValue] === undefined) {
      throw new Error("Invalid message type")
    }

    this._type = newValue;
  }
}

// TEST
const msg = new LogMessageFormat();

console.log(msg.type); // -> log A

msg.type = MessageTypes.B;
console.log(msg.type); // -> log B

msg.type = "no no"; // throws an error
```